# real time application using yii2

Tags: yii2, real-time

I have a project using yii2 framework. I want to make the project become a real time application, maybe it will have realtime notification. But I don't know how to make it. If I use another framework, like laravel, I have gotten some tutorials and it will use vuejs. So, how about yii2? Where I can get the tutorial how to make real time application using yii2?

Comment: You can use SSE to make real time requests and make each part of your application that you want realtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSE to make your application real time. Here is a repository that might help achieving SSE in `Yii2` easier: [Yii2-Sse](https://github.com/odannyc/yii2-sse)

Answer (score 0):

@RiefSapthana If you meaning 'real time' like air traffic control, aerospace, utility control systems; my recommendation is to not use PHP.

[Real Time Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)

If you are asking how to have the browser and server talk back and forth without the need to reload the browser, application like that are typically called '[single page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)' (SPA for short) and the server would be a API service.

The browser application can be written in many ways: pure HTML/CSS/JS, [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/), [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), etc. IMO the majority of the right solutions are [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/) heavy.

[Yii2 has an scaffolding API module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) to help get you started on the server. This type of service is often a 'RESTful' type.